# CanCan authoriziation works on :index but not on :show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

My accessible_by filter is working on the index page, but the show page is failing with the following error.

> NoMethodError in Admin::PublishersController#show
>   undefined method `user_id' for #
>   ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_PublisherUser:0x000001108a9498>

Here are the relevant parts of the controller, model and ability.rb.

Publisher Controller

```
class Admin::PublishersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  def index
    @publishers = Publisher.accessible_by(current_ability).order(:created_at => :desc).page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end

  def show
    @publisher = Publisher.accessible_by(current_ability).find(params[:id])
    @retailer_list = Retailer.where.not(id: @publisher.retailers.map(&:id)).order(:name)
  end
```

Publisher Model

```
class Publisher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publisher_users
  has_many :users, through: :publisher_users
end
```

Ability.rb

```
  if user.has_role? :publisher
    can [:read, :update], Publisher, publisher_users: {user_id: user.id}
  end
```

I've narrowed the problem down to this line in ability.rb. It should be joining publisher and publisher_user tables and applying the user_id to filter the results. Not sure why the model is different on index page than show page.

> can [:read, :update], Publisher, publisher_users: {user_id: user.id}

I have admin users with no restrictions and publisher users that have the above filter which should show only the publishers that have been assigned to a user.

Admin users: see all data.

- Index page: working
- Show page: working

Publisher users: see filtered data.

- Index page: working
- Show page: throws error

The part that is killing me is that the accessible_by for both index and show should be executing the same code from ability.rb.

Thanks for any help you might provide.

Comment: Do you have publishers that do not have published users? I'm also wondering if `can [:read, :update], Publisher, publisher_users: {user_id: user.id}` needs to be formatted differently to account for the fact that a publisher can have multiple published users.

Comment: you have a single model on `show` and a list of models on `index` hence `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`

Comment: phoet, what you are saying makes sense that I'm getting a list of models on the index. Could you explain a little more about how I should fix this? Can I write the "can" so it will work for both?